# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve Oracle database version

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am using debezium oracle connector in kafka connect.While starting connector I am getting below error,

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve Oracle database version
        at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.resolveOracleDatabaseVersion(OracleConnection.java:159)
        at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:71)
        at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector.validateConnection(OracleConnector.java:74)
        at io.debezium.connector.common.RelationalBaseSourceConnector.validate(RelationalBaseSourceConnector.java:52)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.validateConnectorConfig(AbstractHerder.java:400)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.AbstractHerder.lambda$validateConnectorConfig$2(AbstractHerder.java:351)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:oracle:thin:@**.**.*.**:1521/CDB
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.lambda$patternBasedFactory$0(JdbcConnection.java:184)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection$ConnectionFactoryDecorator.connect(JdbcConnection.java:121)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:890)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.connection(JdbcConnection.java:885)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:643)
        at io.debezium.jdbc.JdbcConnection.queryAndMap(JdbcConnection.java:517)
        at io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnection.resolveOracleDatabaseVersion(OracleConnection.java:129)
        ... 10 more
```

I am refering to the link for oracle setup and connector configuration,

```
**https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/oracle.html#setting-up-oracle**
```

**connector-configuration.properties**

```
name=debeziumoraclesource
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.oracle.OracleConnector
database.hostname=**.*.**.**
database.port=1521
database.user=username
database.password=password
database.dbname=CDBNAME
database.server.name=**.*.**.**
tasks.max=1
database.pdb.name=PDBNAME
database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092
database.history.kafka.topic=history.ENTITY_GROUP_PARAMETER_VALUES
database.connection.adaptor=logminer
snapshot.mode=initial
table.include.list=schema.ENTITY_GROUP_PARAMETER_VALUES
```

Also I have download ojdbc8.jar and placed inside kafka/libs folder.I have tried using different version of jars like ojdbc10 and different versions of ojdbc8.Nothing helped me.Also to the point of note I am using oracle19c.Please help me in resolving this issue.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using OJDBC6.jar with all dependencies helped me to resolve the issue. And most importantly i placed the jars in connectors lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

Using OJDBC8.jar helped me solve the problem, the problem appeared as I didn't place the jar on all the servers that were running kafka connect.

Answer (score 0):

I am using confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.7.4 & debezium-connector-oracle connectors. Initialy I was using CLASSPATH in order to resolve the jars but I removed it because of issues.
I copied ojdbc8-19.7.0.0.jar, orai18n-19.7.0.0.jar, ucp-19.7.0.0.jar from the confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc-10.7.4\lib to debezium-connector-oracle\lib and this solved the problem.